# Returning a generator in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, stream, azure-functions

Is it possible to return a generator in an Azure Function? I am trying to stream data *while* it is being created. I tried the following with no luck:

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    def gen():
        for i in range(10):
            yield i

    return func.HttpResponse(gen(), mimetype='text/html')
```

The above yielded `TypeError: reponse is expected to be either of str, bytes, or bytearray, got generator`. Is it possible to do something like this in an Azure Function? I don't necessarily require it to be in Python, but it would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should be possible, May be have a look at this [`example`](https://github.com/jakzale/XTeamDebuggingSample/blob/d8570fca30176397d71552694a85cfc4964bdf3e/src/FunctionsApp/SampleTrigger.cs), you might need to convert the response to a Object/Disctionary.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the number in the generator suppose you could return the `list(gen())`. It will act like the below pic.

[image]

I return the `return func.HttpResponse(str(list(gen())),status_code=200)`, hope this is what you want, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

If your purpose is use flask to return a generator you could refer to the below code.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import json, os

from flask import stream_with_context, request, Response
from flask.app import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    def generate():
        yield 'Hello '
        yield 'world11'
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    uri=req.params['uri']
    with app.test_client() as c:
        doAction = {
            "GET": c.get(uri).data,
            "POST": c.post(uri).data
        }
        resp = doAction.get(req.method).decode()
        return func.HttpResponse(resp, mimetype='text/html')
```

Here is the test result pic.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping to stream the file to avoid carrying a large file in memory. The advantage of streaming is you only store one chunk in memory at a time. My original code was just a toy example, in reality I'm looking to stream a video file for a client to download. The video file will be generated and streamed on-the-fly. Flask has a perfect function for this called "stream_with_context" but I haven't been able to implement it successfully. Here is the documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.stream_with_context

Comment: Doing str(list(gen())) would create the output file THEN send it. But I am looking to stream it while gen() is running (similar to the flask stream_with_context)

Comment: This does successfully serve the file; however, it fully completes the gen() function before returning the response. So the entire response is being held in memory, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Arman Did you get a fix to this? from 3 years ago :)

Comment: @GooJ Unfortunately I never found a way to fix this, at the time I don't think it was possible. I can't say for sure though. If you find a way please share here

Comment: I don't think so, in the docs I read that you can't do streaming, generators etc... However, someone did reply to a question with this, which I'll checkout this weekend https://stackoverflow.com/a/75505297/11181287