# Python - Stream Azure function response

Tags: python, azure, http, azure-functions

How can I stream a result from a HTTP triggered Azure function with Python.

I want to build a secure wrapper around another API call that streams data back. To keep the streaming functionality I want to return the response, or some generator.

The problem is I can only return bytes, strings or numbers as a response.

I want the Azure function to look something like this - but I'll swap out what it is actually generating which is the result from a different API call that is streaming.

```
def main(req):
    request = req.get_json()
    
    def generate():
        for chunk in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
            yield chunk

    return func.HttpResponse(generate())
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stream a result from a HTTP triggered Azure function with
> Python.

You can make use of **Django** **StreamingHttpResponse** class in your Azure HTTP Trigger function to stream HTTP response like below:-

Function code :-

```py
import  logging

from  django.http  import  StreamingHttpResponse

  

import  azure.functions  as  func

  
  

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

  

def  stream_response():

# This generator function will yield chunks of data to be streamed

for  i  in  range(10):

yield  str(i).encode('utf-8')

  

response = StreamingHttpResponse(stream_response(), content_type='text/plain')

response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="my_data.txt"'

return  func.HttpResponse(b''.join(response.streaming_content), status_code=response.status_code, headers=response.headers)
```

**function.json file :-**

```json
{

"scriptFile": "__init__.py",

"bindings": [

{

"authLevel": "anonymous",

"type": "httpTrigger",

"direction": "in",

"name": "req",

"methods": [

  

"get"

]

},

{

"type": "http",

"direction": "out",

"name": "$return"

}

]

}
```

**Output:-**

The Streaming response generated my_data.txt file with the stream_reponse output after the Function ran successfully like below:-

[image]

**File got generated:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know but isn't this part here 

    b''.join(response.streaming_content)

blocking and combining all of the results and only then pushing it out? The point of streaming I suppose is to give the client a response after each yield for instance for ND-json. 

Is there no way of doing it ?